# SEO angular2 multiple routes to one component

Tags: angular, seo, angular2-routing

I created an application with angular2. For internalization and SEO purpose the routes of my application should change. My question is how can I map multiple routes to one component for example the routes:

```
www.test.at/GERMANNAME/Vienna
www.test.at/ENGLISHNAME/Vienna
```

sould map to one component. How can I achieve this with the angular2 router? What I got so far is the following piece of code:

```
export const testRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'ENGLISHNAME', <-- How can i add the GERMANNAME route to this path without copy/pasting the whole path
    component: TestComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':city',
        component: TestListComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Since angular 2 doesn't handles regexs in the path attribute you can't do exactly what you want. However you can declare this route by replacing GERMANNAME and ENGLISHNAME by a route parameter and rectrict the created route in the guard. An other solution would be to create the route dynamically with a map. It will generate x routes but it will be transparent to you.  `['ENGLISHNAME', '...'].map((path) => ({ path, component: TestComponent, children:[/*...*/] }))`